# Android kotlin - set dynamic string inside adapter: inferred type is Int but ContentResolver! was expected

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the code:

```
holder.newmsgOrLastOnline.text = getString(R.string.was_online_minutes_ago, minutes.toString())
```

I get an error on `R.string.was_online_minutes_ago`: `Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but ContentResolver! was expected`

This works in activity/fragment but not in recyclerview adapter, why? How to do this right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is resolved from its id  using context so try using ,

```
holder.newmsgOrLastOnline.text = mContext.getString(R.string.was_online_minutes_ago, minutes.toString());
```

where `mContext` is the Context.